# MongoDB preallocate space for document in capped collection

Tags: mongodb

Documents in capped collection can be updated, but without document size increase. We need to update documents, thus there is a question - is it possible to preallocate space during first insert and the use it for further updates.

Something like : insert document+1mb of zeros, then update document decreasing "fake" zeros.

Comment: It seems possible according to the docs specs of a capped collection

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for a quick proof of concept and then answering your own question on SO for the benefit of the rest of the community :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are essentially describing is manual padding.  I haven't done it in the context of a capped collection before, but there is no reason it would not work.  It can be a good practice in general to avoid expensive moves of a document that grows due to an update.

I have also advised people on SO to do it before in fact when they are looking at the pros/cons of embed versus reference in their schema (store last 5 comments in a blog, fixing the length of the main field, reference for all the history, for example.  The official manual padding docs are here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor#PaddingFactor-ManualPadding

In a capped collection you can update but not grow as you mention, but you can insert a larger document than was in there before, the older docs will then have to make room and multiple may "fall out" of the collection.